# Fix UnnecessaryGString violations in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, codenarc, gstring

When I analyzed my project using CodeNarc I get huge number of `UnnecessaryGString` violations.

I can fix them one by one by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and choosing `Convert to String` option. This is very tedious process though.

Is there any autofix in IntelliJ to replace all unncessary GStrings with Strings? If not, what do I need to do to create my own?

Currently I use error prone replacement from `"([^$\n"]+)"(?!\()` to `'$1'`. It gives some false positives on more complex cases (e.g. with escaping).

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this tool and run it with `--fix`:

https://github.com/nvuillam/npm-groovy-lint